# finding path in HTML

Tags: html, css, node.js, file, path

My file is organized like this:

```
My/
├── public/
│   ├── css/
│   │   ├── sign.css
├── views/
│   ├── register.ejs
```

And I typed in below to access the "sign.css" file:
`<link href="css/sign.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Why is the href path correct?
Shouldn't it be `../public/css/sign.css`
since in order to access sign.css, the step is
"go back one file to My -> go into public -> go into css -> access sing.css"?

Comment: Are you using express? Something like `express.use(express.static(...))` ?

Comment: Knowing which library you're using would be helpful. The HTML/Document Root could be `My/public` which would result in all URLs being `relative` to that path.

Comment: Yes I am using express

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
app.use(express.static('public'))
```

Above code sets public directory from which to serve static assets.
Express looks up the files relative to the static directory, so the name of the static directory is not part of the URL.